# What is causing the 'ambiguous column name' error in SQL and how to fix it?

Tags: sql, mysql

Im having problems on my sql and dont know how to fix it.
Can anyone provide some help and tips for it?

Column 'student_id' in field list is ambiguous

```
SELECT student_id, student.first_name, student.last_name, subject.label, student_score 
FROM score 
INNER JOIN student as stdtab on stdtab.id = student_id
INNER JOIN subject as stab on stab.id = subject_id
```

Answer (score 1):

This error means the `student_id` column name exists in more then one table in the query, use the table name before `student_id`. Like this (if `student_id` is in table `student`):

```
SELECT student.student_id, student.first_name, student.last_name, subject.label, student_score 
FROM score 
INNER JOIN student as stdtab on stdtab.id = student.student_id
INNER JOIN subject as stab on stab.id = subject_id
```